# Show Polymer indeterminate paper-progress when iron-ajax is loading

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying to show a paper-progress when an `iron-ajax` request is in progress with no success. Below is the code for a custom element `get-products-service` which hosts the `iron-ajax` request, and a `products-list` which hosts the `paper-progress`.

This is the whole `products-list` `dom-module`:

```
<dom-module id="product-list">
  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }
    product-card {
      margin-left: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
</style>
<template>
  <template is="dom-if" if="{{loading}}">
    <paper-progress value="10" indeterminate="true"  style="width:100%;"></paper-progress>
  </template>
  <paper-button id="previous" on-tap='previousPage'>Previous</paper-button>
  <paper-button id="next" on-tap='nextPage'>Next</paper-button>

  <get-products-service products="{{products}}" id="productservice"   page="{{page}}" loading="{{loading}}"></get-products-service>
 <div>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{products}}">
     <product-card on-cart-tap="handleCart" product="{{item}}">
       <img width="100" height="100">
       <h3>{{item.name}}</h3>
       <h4>{{item.display_price}}</h4>
     </product-card>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  (function() {
  Polymer({
  is: 'product-list',

  properties: {
    page: {
      type: Number,
      notify: true,
      value: 1
    }
  },
  handleCart: function(event) {

  },
  previousPage: function(event){
   this.page = --this.page;
   console.log("page: "+this.page);
  },
  nextPage: function(event){
    this.page = ++this.page;
    console.log("page: "+this.page);
  }
});
})();
</script>
```

This is the whole `get-products-service`

```
<dom-module id="get-products-service">
  <style>
    :host {
     display: none;
    }
  </style>
<template>
  <iron-ajax id="productsajax"
    url="http://localhost:3003/api/products"
    params='{"token":"mytoken"}'
    method='GET'
    on-response='productsLoaded'
    handleAs="json"
    loading="{{loading}}" >
  </iron-ajax>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
 (function() {

   Polymer({is: 'get-products-service',

     properties: {
       products: {
       type: Array,
       notify: true
     }, 
    page: {
      type: String,
      notify: true,
    },
    perpage: {
      type: String,
      readOnly: true,
      value: "6"
    },
    loading: {
      type: Boolean,
      readOnly: true,
      notify: true,
      value: false
    }
  },

productsLoaded: function(request) {
  console.log(this.$.productsajax.lastResponse);
  responseObject = this.$.productsajax.lastResponse;
  this.products = responseObject.products;
},

ready: function(){
  this.$.productsajax.params.page = this.page;
  this.$.productsajax.params.per_page = this.perpage;
},
observers: [
          'attributesReady(page)'
        ],

attributesReady: function(page) {
    this.page = page;
    this.$.productsajax.params.page = page;
    this.$.productsajax.params.per_page = this.perpage;
    console.log("service page: "+page);
    this.async(function() {
        this.$.productsajax.generateRequest();
      }, 3000);
  }
 });
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Both your `paper-progress` and `get-products-service` have an id of "loading".  This may cause unexpected behavior.

Comment: @Zikes I hadn't noticed that, i have changed it but still not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your best option is to separate your concerns.  First, your `get-products-service`:

```
<dom-module id="get-products-service">
  <style>
    :host {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
  <template>
    <iron-ajax id="productsajax"
      url="http://localhost:3003/api/products"
      method='GET'
      loading="{{loading}}"
      handleAs="json">
    </iron-ajax>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'get-products-service',

      properties: {
        loading: {
          type: Boolean,
          readOnly: true,
          notify: true,
          value: false
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Then, in your `product-list`:

```
<template>
  <template is="dom-if" if="{{loading}}">
    <paper-progress value="10" indeterminate="true" style="width:100%;"></paper-progress>
  </template>
  <get-products-service loading="{{loading}}"></get-products-service>
</template>
```

This way `get-products-service` and `paper-progress` don't have to know anything about each other, and should be more composable elsewhere in your application.

Comment: When I try this, the progress-bar does not appear at all.

Comment: Yes the iron-ajax request works and it returns the expected response. Something else, the `get-products-service` is not in the `dom-bind` template but inside of a list template, I'm not sure whether this makes any difference for your answer although i've tried the `dom-if` template in both the `dom-bind` and the list template and the progress-bar does not appear in both.

Comment: Can you post a more complete example of where `get-products-service` is on the page in relation to `paper-progress`?

Comment: I have edited the question with the location of both the `get-products-service` and `paper-progress`

Comment: @OptimusPette I have updated my answer, please give it another look.

Comment: Not working with the updated answer. When I inspect `iron-ajax` element with the browser, it does not have the loading attribute, which probably means it's null.

Comment: `loading` property needs `notify: true` to be able to push values up the tree.

Comment: Gah, can't believe I missed that. I updated the answer to add it. Thanks @ScottMiles!

Comment: @Zikes where is the value of `loading` property being set to true? I have copied your answer word for word and still cant see the progress-bar.

Comment: @OptimusPette it is from the `iron-ajax` itself.  Did you include the `notify:true` that @ScottMiles pointed out?

Comment: @Zikes I have edited the question to include everything in the `get-products-service` and everthing in the `products-list`. I have also included all your suggestions. Can you please check why it is not working on my end?

Comment: @OptimusPette It looks like you're missing the step that initiates the `iron-ajax` request.  Note the `auto="go"` attribute on the `iron-ajax` in @ScottMiles's answer.  Alternatively, if you want it to execute immediately you can just put the `auto` attribute on.

Comment: I am initiating the request in the `attributesReady` function with `this.$.productsajax.generateRequest();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80412/discussion-between-optimus-pette-and-zikes).

Comment: I am unfortunately unable to access SO chat as it is blocked by my corporate network.

Comment: I can't find any errors in your code that would prevent `loading` from propagating up to the `dom-if` containing the progress bar.  I suspect that being a localhost call it is simply returning the results so quickly that the progress bar does not have an opportunity to appear.  If that is not the case, you may need to arrange a jsbin of your code for us to test in a live environment.

Comment: I think after paper-progress, there was supposed to be a closing template tag, rather than opening a new one (before get-product-service).

Answer (score 3):

Finally I was able to have this working using a combination of @Zikes and @Scott answers. First I seperated the concerns as suggested by @Zikes so i put this in `product-list` element.

```
<template>
  <template is="dom-if" if="{{loading}}">
    <paper-progress value="10" indeterminate="true" style="width:100%;"></paper-progress>
  <template>
  <get-products-service loading="{{loading}}"></get-products-service>
</template>
```

In the `get-products-service` element is where i had to make some changes to have it working. For some reason, i wouldn't get the `loading` property from the `iron-ajax` set to `true`. Therefore @Zikes answer wouldn't work as it was. I had to make a few changes:

1. Explicitly set the value of the `loading` property to `true` just before the `iron-ajax` request is fired.
2. Explicitly set the value of `loading` to `false` when the `on-response` event is fired.
3. For this to work I changed @Zikes answer's `loading` property by removing `readOnly: true;` line.

Using @Scott suggestion, I slowed things down by using:

```
this.async(function() {
        this.$.productsajax.generateRequest();
      }, 5000);
```

to get a chance to see the `progress-bar` .

The resulting `get-products-service` element looks like this:

```
<dom-module id="get-products-service">
  <style>
    :host {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
  <template>
    <iron-ajax id="productsajax"
      url="http://localhost:3003/api/products"
      method='GET'
      on-response='productsLoaded'
      handleAs="json">
    </iron-ajax>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
  Polymer({is: 'get-products-service',
    properties: {
     loading: {
      type: Boolean,
      notify: true,
      value: false
      }
    },
    //on-response callback
     productsLoaded: function(request) {
         this.loading = false;
     },

   //An observer method where ajax request is generated
    attributesReady: function(page) {
      //set the value of loading to true just before generating request
      this.loading = true;
      //slow things to get a chance to see the progress-bar
      this.async(function() {
        this.$.productsajax.generateRequest();
      }, 5000);
    }

  });
</script>
```

I believe @Zikes answer should work too and I'm the one who failed to implement it correctly so I will accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

@Zikes has the right answer. I'm supplementing here with a fully working implementation (only for Chrome, x-platform requires a few tweaks):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <base href="http://milestech.net/components/">

  <link href="iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html" rel="import">
  <link href="paper-progress/paper-progress.html" rel="import">

</head>
<body>

  <use-service></use-service>

  <dom-module id="get-products-service">
    <template>

      <iron-ajax url="iron-ajax/bower.json" auto="{{go}}" handle-as="text" last-response="{{products}}"></iron-ajax>

    </template>
    <script>

      Polymer({

        properties: {
          products: {
            notify: true,
            value: null
          }
        },

        ready: function() {
          // this bit just because otherwise it's too fast to see
          this.async(function() {
            this.go = true;
          }, 1000);
        }
      });

    </script>
  </dom-module>

  <dom-module id="use-service">
    <template>

      <template is="dom-if" if="{{!products}}">
        <paper-progress value="10" indeterminate="true" style="width:100%;"></paper-progress>
      </template>

      <get-products-service products="{{products}}"></get-products-service>

      <pre>{{products}}</pre>

    </template>
    <script>

      Polymer({});

    </script>
  </dom-module>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you tell me why with Zikes answer the `loading` property is not being set to true even when the request is loading?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's kinda late, but I ran into a similar dilemma and decided to expose the API.
This way I could show the exact percent of progress of the XHR request.

#### Note: *Very Hacky*

I did this by overriding the default generateRequest() method, with a few additions.

```js
app.$.productsajax.generateRequest = function() {
  var request = (document.createElement('iron-request'));
  var requestOptions = this.toRequestOptions();
  ///**=============================================///
  ///**   Added to expose progress - Super Hacky  **///
  var me = this;
  request.ap_obs = function(a) {
    me.progress = a;
    me._notifyChange("progress")
  };
  request._addObserverEffect("progress", "ap_obs")
    ///**===========================================**///
  this.activeRequests.push(request);
  request.completes.then(
    this._boundHandleResponse
  ).catch(
    this._handleError.bind(this, request)
  ).then(
    this._discardRequest.bind(this, request)
  );
  request.send(requestOptions);
  this._setLastRequest(request);
  this._setLoading(true);
  this.fire('request', {
    request: request,
    options: requestOptions
  });
  return request;
}
```

So now your element can look like:

```html
<template>
  <iron-ajax url="iron-ajax/bower.json" progress="{{progress}}" loading="{{activePageReq}}" auto="{{go}}" handle-as="text" last-response="{{products}}"></iron-ajax>
  <paper-progress hide$="{{!activePageReq}}" value="{{progress.loaded}}" ,max="{{progress.total}}"></paper-progress>
</template>
```

Comment: Why is this 'very hacky'? Is it not secure or is it a 'quick and dirty' solution?

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it assumes that the implementation of `generateRequest` will never change. This means any updates to the component will be overwritten by this hack here. (
ie. It is a *quick and dirty* solution)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wanted to keep the progress bar always visible in a menu area, and start / stop it from different elements when doing some work that might take some time.

The progress is indeterminate by default on loading

```
<paper-progress id="working" indeterminate ></paper-progress>
```

We have a global namespace object app and I just add there a function as follow

```
  app.working = function(flag){
    document.querySelector("#working").indeterminate = flag;
  };
```

In that case, when the initial loading is done, I just do

```
app.working(false);
```

And it can be started / stopped later on from any element in the app, just by doing

```
app.working(true);
// ... long process
app.working(false);
```